# How to get default mail credentials in nokia s40 phones ?

Tags: java, email, java-me, nokia-s40

Is there any system defined function/method to get default mail credentials for a particular user and use it in our application for sending mail for nokia s40 ?

Answer (score 1):

No, but Nokia supports platformRequest("mailto:") for some S40 devices.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/invoking-applications/invoking-applications-in-java-me.html